# The metric space $(l^1 \mathbb{(N)}, d_{l^1})$ is separable.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

My goal is to prove the title. The metric space $(l^1 \mathbb{(N)}, d_{l^1})$ is separable. Some definitions:
$$l^1 \mathbb{(N)} = \left\{f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \sum^{\infty}_{j = 1} |f(j)| < + \infty\right\}$$
$$d_{l^1}(f,g) = \sum^{\infty}_{j=1}|f(j) - g(j)|$$
Here's what I have so far, but I'm worried that it's incorrect because I never use the metric $d_{l^1}$, and failing to use every aspect of the setup of a problem usually doesn't bode well. I suspect that there may be something incorrect about my assertion that the set $A$ is countable. Am I doing something wrong or is this correct?

$\textit{Proof.}$ Define the set $$A_{m, n} = \left\{f \in l^1 \mathbb{(N)} : \frac{m}{n} \leq \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} |f(j)| \leq \frac{m+1}{n} \text{ where } m \in \mathbb{N}_0, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$$
Then
$$A = \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{N_0}, n \in \mathbb{N}} A_{m,n}$$
is countable since it is the countable union of countable sets. Next, let $B(f, r)$ be the open ball in $l^1 \mathbb{(N)}$ centered at $f$ with radius $r$. For contradiction, suppose $B(f, r) \cap A = \emptyset$. Then each $f_0 \in B(f, r)$ has the property that $f_0 \notin A_{m,n}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N_0}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. This means there is no rational number which bounds $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} |f_0(j)|$ from above, and so $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} |f_0(j)|$ diverges to $\infty$. This is a contradiction since it implies $B(f,r) \notin l^1 \mathbb{(N)}$.

We have then that $B(f,r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$, and so $A$ is countable and dense in $l^1 \mathbb{(N)}$, proving that the metric space $(l^1 \mathbb{(N)}, d_{l^1})$ is separable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_{m,n}$ is not countable. If you take one $f$ with $\sum |f(j)|=\frac {m+\frac1  2} n$ then $(1+\epsilon)f \in A_{m,n}$ for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

For a correct proof consider sequences $(a_n)$ which are $0$ after some stage with $a_n$ rational for each $n$.

Comment: Thank you! I really needed to examine the notion of countable sets more. I'm digging into what you suggested and this is actually a very interesting problem. Thanks again